# Octopusdeploy deploy multiple sites from one package

Tags: iis-7, octopus-deploy

I have a unique situation where I have a package created by TeamCity which contains two sites. For e.g. package-1.0.zip contains Site1 and Site2 in it.

How can I deploy these two sites using octopus deploy? Both sites have their own application pool, config transformation, etc..

Is there any way, I can reference those two folders inside the package when creating IIS site deployment steps so that I can create two steps to deploy those two different sites?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by having two "Deploy to IIS" steps in your Process and changing the Physical Path setting to "Relative path under package installation directory"

[image: relative path setting]

This should allow you to configure each site with different IIS settings while still using the same package.

**Edit: based on your comments, this process may work for you**

1. Use the Deploy a Package step to deploy the package contents to the target machine.
2. Enable custom deployment scripts (click "Configure Features" next to the Save button on the step details and then select "Custom deployment scripts").
3. Write a custom deployment script to copy Site1 and Site2 to the appropriate folders.
4. If you need to configure IIS after that step (site, app pool, etc) there are many [Community Step templates](https://library.octopus.com/listing) for those actions. Search for IIS to see the full listing.

Comment: ryan, I tried it out and it created site1 fine but it still copies Site2 with it. My site2 resides somewhere else. So directory structure is something like: C:/.....Installation_dir_for_site1/Site1 but it also contains: C:/.....Installation_dir_for_site1/Site2

Comment: What I want to do is: I want to take only Site1 from the package and deploy it and then in the next step, I want to take Site2 and deploy it. Both sites are using different settings for their app pool and resides in very different location. For business purpose, I will have to create just one package for both sites and I can't separate it out

Comment: To do exactly as you are asking, you will likely have to write custom deploy scripts to handle the different site configurations. I don't think you'll be able to to do with with the Deploy an IIS Site step if you need them to be deployed separately to custom folders.

*hit save too soon, more details coming*

Answer (score 0):

We do a similar deployment, Where octopus receives the package containing multiple sites.

We break it into different packages, unzipping and zipping the package and using octopkg push as a seperate library and deploy them as different sites, using custom install directories.